# How can I set opacity of the reflection when using -webkit-box-reflect?

Tags: reflection, webkit, css, opacity

I've been playing with the -webkit-box-reflect property in Chrome and can achieve a reflection that fades with the following code (it's example code from the [Webkit blog](http://webkit.org/blog/182/css-reflections/)):

```
-webkit-box-reflect:
  below 5px 
  -webkit-gradient(
  linear, left top, left bottom, 
  from(transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), to(white)
  );
```

Problem is, I want to set the opacity for the mask to a more subtle setting, but it seems to be choking on rgba(). Has anybody been able to successfully get different levels of opacity?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
-webkit-box-reflect:
  below 5px 
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), 
  color-stop(0.5, transparent), 
  to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)));
```

Is this the code you were looking for? :)

Comment: It does not work like a charm. I added this: `* { -webkit-box-reflect: below 5px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent),  color-stop(0.5, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5))); }` to the current page and Safari went slow.